# Matriz em bloco de memória

Tags: c, memória

Olá, pessoal!

Estou com mais uma dúvida sobre matrizes, mais precisamente na ocupação de memória de cada uma.

Estou tentando simular o mesmo que o cara desse vídeo [Performance x64: Cache 2 Cache Blocking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G92BCtfTwOE)
 fez, mas não está batendo os tempos de execução. Ele usou alguma biblioteca extra para geração das matrizes.

Preciso provar no código que quando divido a memória em blocos a execução é mais rápida, ou seja, com menos misses. Alguém tem ideia de onde estou errando? Obrigado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BLOCO 10
#define DIMENSAO 100

int main(){

  double matrizA[DIMENSAO][DIMENSAO];
  double matrizB[DIMENSAO][DIMENSAO];
  double matrizC[DIMENSAO][DIMENSAO];
  double matrizD[DIMENSAO][DIMENSAO];
  double matrizE[DIMENSAO][DIMENSAO];

  srand(time(NULL));

  //matrizA
  for(int i = 0; i < DIMENSAO; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < DIMENSAO; j++){
      matrizA[i][j] = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX*10.0;
    }
  }

  //matrizB
  for(int i = 0; i < DIMENSAO; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < DIMENSAO; j++){
      matrizB[i][j] = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX*10.0;
    }
  }

  //Matriz B (transposta)
  for(int i = 0; i < DIMENSAO; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < DIMENSAO; j++){
      for (int k = 0; k < DIMENSAO; k++) {
        matrizD[j][i] = matrizB[i][j];
      }

    }
  }

  //produto matrizA x matrizB
  clock_t t1;
  t1 = clock();
  for(int linha = 0; linha < DIMENSAO; linha++){
    for(int coluna = 0; coluna < DIMENSAO; coluna++){
      for (int k = 0; k < DIMENSAO; k++) {
        matrizC[coluna][linha] += matrizA[k][linha] * matrizB[coluna][k];
      }
    }
  }
  t1 = clock() - t1;
  printf("Tempo de execução A x B: %.2lf \n", ((double)t1)/((CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000)));


  //Produto de A x B(transposta)
  clock_t t2;
  for(int linha = 0; linha < DIMENSAO; linha+=BLOCO){
    for(int coluna = 0; coluna < DIMENSAO; coluna+=BLOCO){

      t2 = clock();
      for(int blocoLinha = linha; blocoLinha < linha + BLOCO; blocoLinha++){
        for(int blocoColuna = coluna; blocoColuna < coluna + BLOCO; blocoColuna++){
          for (int k = 0; k < DIMENSAO; k++) {
            matrizE[blocoColuna][blocoLinha] += matrizA[k][blocoLinha] * matrizC[blocoColuna][k];
          }
        }
      }
      t2 = clock() - t2;
      printf("Tempo de execução A x B (transposta): %.2lf \n", ((double)t2)/((CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000)));
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: *"mas não está batendo os tempos de execução"*...quais os tempos que você está obtendo e qual seria o resultado esperado? Qual é o processador e memória que você está utilizando? Qual o sistema operacional? Qual compilador? Quais opções de compilação? Existem outros programas sendo executados enquanto você efetua o teste? Todos esses detalhes (e talvez alguns outros) podem influenciar muito no resultado! Recomendo você editar a pergunta e acrescentar o máximo de detalhes para poder obter uma resposta mais assertiva

Comment: Outro detalhe importante é que no vídeo indicado na pergunta, além do "cara" não informar esses detalhes acima, **aparentemente**, o código que ele utiliza para o teste parece ter outros problemas sérios, pois o método `Matrix::MUL` que ele testa: aloca memória, gera o resultado numa matriz temporária, copia o resultado para a matriz de destino e desaloca a matriz temporária, chama métodos, etc., e para testar o desempenho do cache, isso tudo não pode ser incluído **de jeito nenhum** no tempo de execução do trecho de código testado.

Comment: Olá, @Gomiero, obrigado pelas respostas. Então, algumas coisas que disse eu realmente não prestei atenção, mas no caso da alocação de memória eu fiz questão de não tem, pra realmente observar o desempenho nos dois casos. Estou usando Debian, GCC, Core i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz, 8GB de RAM. Vou analisar o código novamente e volto a postar e melhorar a pergunta. O "cara" do vídeo é o Chris Rose, só conheço desse desse vídeo mesmo, desculpe não ter colocado o nome dele, falha minha.